# foreach loop for xml

Tags: php, laravel

I have following xml getting loaded in my PHP code;

```
<SiteAlarmDetails>
    <AlertId>89637</AlertId>
    <SiteCode>20157498</SiteCode>
    <SiteName>newport</SiteName>
</SiteAlarmDetails>



$alertXml = simplexml_load_string( $tableAlarm->AlarmDetails);

echo (string) $alertXml->AlertId;  //prints **89637**
```

Now I try to traverse this XML nodes;

```
foreach($alertXml->children() as $alerts) 
{
   $alertId = (string)$alerts->AlertId;
   echo $alertId;//I do not see anything
}
```

Is above right approach to traverse AlertId in the foreach loop?

Comment: Do you want to loop over these `AlertId, SiteCode`?

Comment: `foreach($alertXml->children() as $alerts) { print_r($alerts); }` What happens when you do this?

Comment: @SahilGulati Yes. I might get multiple childern elements inside one parent element

Comment: `$alertXml->children()` will return a collection of `AlertId`, `SiteCode` and `SiteName` nodes. They all contain plain text content. What is it exactly that you're trying to do?

Comment: @Phil I want to read my AlertId inside foreach loop. I get very big XML. I might get multiple ALertId covered with Different root elements. Here I provided a simple xml and asking How to read that Alert ID inside foreach

Comment: In your example, there is nothing really to iterate. How about you use a better XML sample?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trying simple `foreach` will be helpful. Just for accessing single value (eg `AlertId`) you can use `$alertXml->AlertId;`.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/850095)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$xmlString=<<<XML
<SiteAlarmDetails>
    <AlertId>89637</AlertId>
    <SiteCode>20157498</SiteCode>
    <SiteName>newport</SiteName>
</SiteAlarmDetails>
XML;


$alertXml = simplexml_load_string( $xmlString);
foreach($alertXml as $key => $child)
{
    echo $key ."=".(string)$alertXml->{$key};
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

**Output:**

```
AlertId=89637
SiteCode=20157498
SiteName=newport
```

Comment: Thank you, If i waat to read a specific key(ie: ALertId), how should I read it?

Comment: @Ratha you can use just `echo $alertXml->AlertId;`

Comment: And if I have <SiteAlarmDeatils> tag covered with another root tag,(eg: <Test>) how should I traverse for AlertId?

Comment: @Ratha for that you can use `XPath`  http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php